# What's the difference between Unanswered and Questions > unanswered?

Tags: support, user-interface

What's the difference between the button at the top called "Unanswered" and the tab under "Questions" button called "unanswered"?

It is not the same answers that appears in both, so they must have a different function.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "unanswered" page shows only the unaswered questions, which you can sort by different criteria.

The "unanswered" tab in questions is  a sort option for ALL questions (answered and unanswered) : using "unanswered" tab in questions means that unanswered questions will be listed first (and answered at the end).

Comment: Seems like somebody's overloading the "unanswered" definition.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. The Unanswered page seems to filter out questions with negative scores. The Unanswered tab also doesn't have the same *count* as the other tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The "unanswered" page from the top button lets you to sort unanswered question by various criteria.

The questions=>unanswered page does not have any additional sorting options.