# Discrepancy in the number of "questions with no accepted or upvoted answers"

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

I asked [a version of this question earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244330/discrepency-in-unanswered-questions-counts), but there seems to have been some confusion about what was meant, so I will try to be as clear as possible.

I **am NOT** asking for an explanation of the difference between "questions with no answer" and "questions with no accepted or upvoted answers".  I am asking why there are *two* different numbers reported for the latter category.<sup>1</sup>

On [this site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions), with `Unanswered` selected in the *upper* tab bar and `newest` selected in the *lower* tab bar I currently get

## 1,382

These are explicitly described as "questions with no upvoted or accepted answers".  However, if I select `Questions` in the *upper* tab and `unanswered` in the *lower* tab bar, I get:

## 1,433

This is only a difference of 50, but these numbers are live, and so I'm curious as to which 50 questions count as being "unanswered" that do not count as "questions with no upvoted or accepted answers".

Part of the reason I'm curious here is because if we subtract the number of questions with *no* answer (~1100), this is the difference between 280 and 330, which is not insignificant.

---

<sup>1. Just in case that is not utterly and totally clear: Please, please, please do not explain the difference between "unanswered questions" and "answers with no upvoted or accepted answers".  I understand.  That's not the question.</sup>

Comment: By the way, I don't understand your footnote. What is  the difference between "unanswered questions" and "answers with no upvoted or accepted answers"?

Comment: @Raff An answer "with no upvoted or accepted answers" might still have an answer, and in that sense is not "unanswered".  So, e.g., in the last paragraph I've referred to the fact that there are 1100 questions with no answer what-so-ever, meaning the difference is questions that have at least one answer, just not one that was either accepted or upvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Unanswered* tab in main navigation excludes questions with negative score. You can see this by sorting it by votes and navigating to the [last page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=157&tab=votes).

The *Questions/unanswered* does not exclude negatively scored questions, so its count is a bit higher. For example, as of now [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?page=161&sort=unanswered) has negatively scored questions.

By the way, the accepted answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132080/259867) is incorrect.